# Max Of Average - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to repeat what I have done on excel in mysql.

Averaging multiple columns and getting the highest/max value of this calculation.

Here is the data and that I have worked out in excel -

[image]

The values in orange is excels Average function and the green is excels Max function.

I am using the following SQL to get the same results in MYSQL.

```
SELECT AVG(HOUR_8 + HOUR_9 + HOUR_10 + HOUR_11 + HOUR_12 + HOUR_13 + HOUR_14 
                  + HOUR_15 + HOUR_16)/9 AS AVERAGE_HOUR 
FROM HOURS
```

But the Best average that is output is Now if i carry out the same equation in mysql the Best average is **13.51851852**

I have tried to combine the sql with MAX but it simply doesn't allow you to do that.

Is there any other way of repeating what I have done in excel in MYSQL correctly?

Comment: Try using a nested query. `SELECT MAX(s.AVERAGE_HOUR)
    FROM (SELECT AVG(HOUR_8 + HOUR_9 + HOUR_10 + HOUR_11 + HOUR_12 + HOUR_13 + HOUR_14 + HOUR_15 + HOUR_16)/9 AS AVERAGE_HOUR FROM HOURS) AS s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `AVG()` function.  That is an aggregation function and all the values are in a single row.

Instead, you can just calculate the value arithmetically.  Then, you can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`, or just `MAX()` to get the value:

```
select t.*,
       ((hour_8 + hour_9 + hour_10 + hour_11 + hour_12 + hour_13 + hour_14 + hour_15 + hour_16)/9) as avg_hour
from t
order by avg_hour desc
limit 1;
```

This gives all the other values in the row.  If you just want the maximum average:

```
select max((hour_8 + hour_9 + hour_10 + hour_11 + hour_12 + hour_13 + hour_14 + hour_15 + hour_16)/9) as max_avg_hour
from t;
```

Comment: An order would be a bit Heavy on a huge table compare to the MAX version, don't you think ?

Comment: @AxelH . . . The `max()` should be faster, but if you want the individual columns, then the `order by` is handy.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree, just using the ordered one with a `limit 1` is not useful since you can do it with the max query ;) but to list everything it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the `AVG` function wrong there, because it gets the column AVG. You should be using something like this:

```
SELECT (HOUR_8 + HOUR_9 + HOUR_10 + HOUR_11 + 
    HOUR_12 + HOUR_13 + HOUR_14 + HOUR_15 + 
    HOUR_16) / 9 AS AVG_HOUR FROM HOURS
```

This gives you a single column containing each row's hour averages.

Now you should select the maximum of them by Using `MAX()` function of mySQL.

```
SELECT MAX(AVG_HOUR) FROM
(
    SELECT (HOUR_8 + HOUR_9 + HOUR_10 + HOUR_11 + 
        HOUR_12 + HOUR_13 + HOUR_14 + HOUR_15 + 
        HOUR_16)/9 AS AVERAGE_HOUR FROM HOURS
)
```

Comment: Still didn't work, outputted 14.70370370 as the best average

Comment: Maybe your database data and excel data are different?

Comment: @TahaPaksu You kept the AVG in the MAX ;)

Comment: Ups. my mistake :)